# LINQ - Convert String to Datetime Order By

Tags: c#

```
var chartData = (from r in _db.CashFlowHistory
where r.CompanyTaxCode == taxnumber
            group r by new
            {
                r.CreatedDate,
            }
            into g
            select new
{Date = g.Key.CreatedDate})
```

Result :

```
Date

<li>1.05.2019 
<li>8.05.2019 
<li>25.04.2019 
<li>23.04.2019
<li>6.05.2019 
<li>7.05.2019 
<li>28.04.2019 
<li>30.04.2019 
<li>26.04.2019
```

Created date string format, I want to sort it by date.

Comment: Is `r.CreatedDate` a `string`?Have you tried to convert it to a date yet? If so, show us that.

Comment: Use `.OrderBy` to sort it

Answer (score 1):

```
chartData.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
```

Comment: I can't sort the string because it is (CreatedDate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming `CreatedDate` is string):

```
var dateArray = chartData
  .Select(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Replace("<li>", "").Trim()))
  .OrderBy(d => d)
  .ToArray();
```

or

```
var orderedArray = chartData
  .OrderBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Replace("<li>", "").Trim()))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: @ArifÖZELCİ I completely do not understand

Comment: https://d.pr/i/btiAdN code is here, I can't sort the date on this code, because CreatedDate is a string

Comment: @ArifÖZELCİ I gave you my answer, try it

Comment: <li> they do not already code as well. d.pr/i/btiAdN code is here,

Comment: @ArifÖZELCİ Sorry, I do not understand you, is my answer working or not?

Comment: OP didn't manage to paste his results into the Question. The <li> tags are not part of the results.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks for this. I converted datatime in my sql db, and it messed up my OrderBy Linq query. The DateTime.Parse solution you gave solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (date1!=null)
        {
            custQuery = custQuery.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.docDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= date1);
        }
        if (date2 != null)
        {
            custQuery = custQuery.Where(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.docDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= date2);
        }

        return custQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi,I didn't ask that. Thanks.